# `UnsafePartial` method works on non-partial function too - Purescript?

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

I'm trying to do something similar to what `Partial` type class does, so to understand Partial constraint better I started experimenting with it...

I created a normal function,

```
goodFn :: Int -> Effect Int
goodFn a = pure $ a + 1
```

and I tried applying `unsafePartial` function on it...

```
unsafePartial $ goodFn 1
```

It worked, that's my question how it worked even though `goodFn` isn't partial?

```
unsafePartial :: forall a. (Partial => a) -> a
```

The function I pass `goodFn` doesn't have `Partial` constraint, then why the compiler didn't complain?

If that's the correct behaviour, how do I enforce my function to be always called after applying it to a unwrapper function.

Like how `unsafePartial` function always need to be applied to partial functions(aka function with partial constraint) before actually calling the function

(Can we prevent calling a function directly? Make it callable only after applying it to a runner function, like unsafePartial)

Comment: ps: I don't want to wrap the function with a newtype

Answer (score 0):

I have a idea, I will pass an extra argument which I don't expose,

```
data PartialSecret = PartialSecret
```

then in the same file, I create my unwrapper function,

```
runPartialFn :: forall a. (PartialSecret -> a) -> a 
runPartialFn fn = fn PartialSecret
```

Now I annotate all my function with my `PartialSecret` as first argument,

```
fn1 :: PartialSecret -> Int -> Int 
fn1 partial a = a+1
```

I can also do recursion with it, without again using `runPartialFn` like,

```
fn1 :: PartialSecret -> Int -> Int 
fn1 partial 0 = 0
fn1 partial a = 1 + fn1 partial (a-1)
```

Now I can't call any of my function(from other place) without applying `runPartialFn`

Is it a good approach?

Comment: Note that this doesn't solve your issue with how `Partial` behaves: people are free to lift their functions into `PartialSecret -> ...` via `const`. The compiler is effectively doing the same for `Partial`, just using an invisible `const` to dismiss the instance dictionary

Comment: Brilliant, I didnt think that way... so how can i resolve that?

Comment: But i guess i'm okay with it, as I didn't want developer to mistakenly pass normal function to my method, if they are using `const` then they are aware of this `partialSecret`...

Comment: You'd either need to newtype the function or return value, which you didn't want, or instead require that functions produce the `PartialSecret` rather than receive it (inside a tuple perhaps with the actual return value). However, It's not trivial to make your runner require functions that return in this way in the presence of currying